# kotlin+room error : [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: int cannot be converted to an Element

Tags: android, android-room

I faced an error related to Int:

*[kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: int cannot be converted to an Element*

I don't understand why it happens. Also I couldn't find solution in similar questions.I think this error means that the dao can't deal with Int and can't update the database.

Here is my code.

```
@Entity(tableName = "Promise")
data class Promise(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val index : Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "date") val date : Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "content") val content : String
)


@Dao
interface PromiseDao {
    @Query("Select * from Promise")
    fun getAll() :List<Promise>

    @Query("select * from Promise order by date DESC limit 1")
    fun getRecent() :Promise

    @Insert
    fun insertPromise(date: Int, content:String)

}

@Database(entities = arrayOf(Promise::class), version = 1)
abstract class PromiseDatabase : RoomDatabase(){
    abstract fun promiseDao() : PromiseDao

    companion object{
        private var INSTANCE : PromiseDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context : Context) : PromiseDatabase{
            var tmpPromiseDB = INSTANCE

            if(tmpPromiseDB == null){
                tmpPromiseDB = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, PromiseDatabase::class.java, "promise_database").build()
                INSTANCE = tmpPromiseDB
            }
            return tmpPromiseDB
        }
    }
}


class PostActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var promiseDatabase : PromiseDatabase
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post)
        promiseDBinit()
        val cancelPost_imageView = findViewById(R.id.cancelPost_button) as ImageView
        val postHead_textView = findViewById(R.id.postHead_textView) as TextView
        val writePost_button = findViewById(R.id.writePost_button) as Button



        cancelPost_imageView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            onBackPressed()
        })
        writePost_button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            //DB에 올리는 과정
            var content = StringBuilder()
            content.append(postHead_textView.text.toString())
            promiseDatabase.promiseDao().insertPromise(System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), content.toString())
        })
    }
    fun promiseDBinit(){
        promiseDatabase = PromiseDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Room @Insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Insert) syntax

Change this:

```
@Insert
    fun insertPromise(date: Int, content:String)
```

to this:

```
@Insert
    fun insertPromise(promise: Promise)
```

And this:

```
promiseDatabase.promiseDao().insertPromise(System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), content.toString())
```

to this:

```
promiseDatabase.promiseDao().insertPromise(Promise(System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), content.toString()))
```